# sql update table column based on values across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables (only relevant columns shown with example values):

**requests**

```
id website_id
=============
1  NULL
2  NULL
3  NULL
```

**request_fields**

```
id requests_id field_id field_response
=============================================

1  1                  1        some site
2  1                  2        some user
3  2                  1        some other site
4  2                  2        some other user
5  3                  1        some site
6  3                  2        rando user
```

**websites**

```
id website_name
===============
1  some site
2  some other site
```

My goal is to update `requests.website_id` to be the value from `websites.id`, but this value is determined by selecting from `request_fields` where `requests.id=request_fields.requests_id`and
`request_fields.field_id=1` and `request_fields.response=websites.website_name`

So IOW, for each row in `requests`, use `requests.id` to select `request_fields.field_resonse` from `request_fields` where `request_fields.request_id=requests.id` and `request_fields.field_id=1` and then select `websites.id` from `websites` where `websites.name=[the request_fields.field_resonse value]` and then set the original `requests.id` value to that `websites.id` value.

So end result would be

**requests**

```
id website_id
=============
1  1
2  2
3  1
```

Is this possible to do? I've been trying to wrap my head around it and I think it involves inner joins and stuff but this is a bit much for me.

**edit:**

This is my current attempt, but I'm not sure I got it right?

```
update requests
inner join request_fields on requests.id=request_fields.request_id
inner join websites on request_fields.response=website.name
set requests.website_id=websites.id
```

I'm kind of eyeballing the table and it seems to have worked but again.. I'm a bit over my head here and not sure if I'm about to mess something up on my real table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join all 3 tables in the `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE requests r
INNER JOIN request_fields rf ON rf.requests_id = r.id
INNER JOIN websites w ON w.website_name = rf.field_response
SET r.website_id = w.id
WHERE rf.field_id = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fe9945818d3f37016c998908ce23433).